# Grafana dynamically display new hosts added by collectd

Tags: influxdb, grafana, collectd

How to get grafana to dynamically add graphs for newly added hosts? For example, I have grafana chart to display load average for existing hosts. When I add a new host, the collectd will send the new host metrics to influxdb. But every time I have to manually add one more graph in grafana which is not desired? Is there a way to get grafana automatically plot the new host metrics without changing grafana?

Comment: which influxdb version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make use of the [Grafana HTTP api](http://docs.grafana.org/reference/http_api/) and update your dashboard by adding the new graph that you want. This practically means that you have to:

- use the api to take the json of the dashboard
- handle this data and add your extra code for the new panel that you want to add
- use the api again to update the dashboard

The hierarchy is simple: a dashboard has rows and rows have panels. Probably you will have to add some json code inside panels. Go check your json file and all these will make sense to you...

Comment: I came across something like this: http://wahlnetwork.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/cpu-stack-grafana.jpg  . But I do not see the series option in my grafana. Collectd only provide metrics and host is one of the columns. I think something similar to above graph is what I need. Just not sure how to get the series. I do have naming convention in my hosts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regexp patterns in InfluxDB 0.8](https://influxdb.com/docs/v0.8/api/query_language.html#selecting-multiple-series) (see also the [0.9 equivalent docs](https://influxdb.com/docs/v0.9/query_language/data_exploration.html#regular-expressions-in-queries)) to match all your newly added hosts. InfluxDB regexps use the [Golang syntax](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/syntax/).

For example, to match all series starting with `stats.cpuNUMBER`:

```
series: /^stats\.cpu\d+/
select: avg(load)
```

However this way you won't get one new plot for each newly added host, but a line for every host in the same plot.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add regex in your select clause.

> SELECT mean(value) FROM /logstash.*.requests.count/ WHERE $timeFilter
>   GROUP BY time($interval)

Above script will plot each series matching above regex automatically for all hosts without changing the grafana.

logstash.ABC1.requests.count

logstash.ABC2.requests.count

logstash.ABC3.requests.count

When ABC4 host is added and it is shipped correctly, new graph will be plotted automatically.